# Custom Objects fields not showing up on Edit Form

Tags: custom-object, migration

I am trying to migrate an Object from One Instance of sales force to another. Following one of the online link I created object manually to target instance and copied Fields, layouts from the from source XML to target object XML.

I was able to deploy without any errors. Also, can see all fields showing up on Object setup page.

Though, when I try to create new record, I only see one of the lookup columns. All other fields are not visible on edit form.

How should I avoid this issue in Migration of fields? How can I enable those fields to show up now on Edit form.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Review the FLS for each field and make sure that the user profile has the ability to edit the field.

Click the field name in the object.
Click Security
Ensure read and edit are check for the appropriate profiles.

Simple creating the object via XML does not copy the security of the Object to the new instance.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. I am able to make those fields visible by clicking on field name.

Comment: Thank you! Though, what could be more seemless way to migrate a custom object? Can I copy security settings the same way? copying xml?

Comment: Are the orgs connected? If so use a changeset. If not AND the profiles are the same you could try the ant migration tool. I do not use it so I am not sure of the complexities....